# Android Material Library

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

The different Android Versions (even older ones) have still a big marketshare. For consultation I took the [Distribution Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/) into consideration.

[image]

When I started with Android Development I thought that the Standard components will have Material Style by default set. But as further as I came, I recognized that the "Standard" and Support Components don't have the "newest" Guidelines implemented.

So I was trying to understand why and found the [com.google.android.material Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md). I think this is a step into the right direction but I got a bit suspicious when I read the "Getting Started" Guide. Inside the guide it states "download the Android P Preview using the SDK manager".

Now I'm questioning, does that mean, that when I want to support all Android Versions with the biggest marketshares (all Versions till 5.1), I can't use this library, or is it still backwards comaptible?

Further I recognized, that when I want to support "older" Android Versions I need to use the [Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/). But I always questioned, isn't this a bit senseless? I mean, most of us want to bring their app to as much customers as possible. Due to the fact that 5.1 and 6.0 have a marketshare of approximately 30% does anyone really drop support for these devices and uses just "plain" Components not contained in the Support Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first library you mentioned (Material Components) works on all supported versions of Android, which currently is 14+. It internally uses Support Library and adds on top of their controls. You can use whichever you like and you'll be good on 5.1 and 6.0.

The bad part is that none of these libraries actually fully implement the guidelines nor backport features. When I last checked, there was no cut corners, no backdrop layout, no saturation fade for images, etc. Shadows, ripples and drawing order don't work on API 4.x, colored shadows don't work on API older than 28, etc.

If you need Material Design as in the guidelines, you need a 3rd party library or a lot of work.

Comment: Flutter addresses this problem by providing the exact same experience throughout all API levels.